# Probability Hitchhiking

Tags: probability

Richard is hitchhiking from Decatur, AL, to Amherst, VA. The probability that Richard will see a car within the next $20$ minutes is $\frac{609}{625}$. What is the probability that he will see a car within the next $5$ minutes? Assume that the probability of seeing a car at any moment is uniform (the same) for the entire $20$ minutes.

If $P(5 min)=x$ why doesn't $x^4=\frac{609}{625}$

Comment: Recommendation:  boil the problem down to its essential.  Do we care that the person's name is "Richard"?  Do we care that the cities are "Decatur, AL" and "Amherst, VA"?  This will improve your understanding and your problem solving.

Comment: Why do you think that should be the answer?  It would give $x>1$ which is not a valid probability.

Comment: @saulspatz i have made the correction, i have viewed other solutions to the problem and it has used [P(5min)=1-P(viewing no car in 5 min)] so {(1-x)^4=1-(609/625)} and was wondering if mutiplicative property worked for {1-x} why doesnt it work for just {x}

Comment: In order for the MathJax formatting to take effect, you have to to enclose it in `$` signs.  It's not that "it doesn't work" for $x$, but that you have to consider what you are computing.  $x^4$ would be the probability that you see a car in ear of the next next $4$ $5$-minute intervals.  That's not what you're interested in.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for the formatting tip, i truly appreciate it. With regards to your second sentence, can you clear that solution to me, it doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: I meant exactly what Siong said in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see a car in $20$ minutes, we don't have to see a car in every $5$ minutes.

The probability that you **don't** see a car in $20$ minutes is equal to the probability that you **don't** see any car in the consecutive $4$ $5$-minutes intervals.

Comment: thank you for the well explained solution